# Como endereço do localhost na rede local

Tags: windows, xampp

Estou testando uma aplicação web localmente pelo pc e celular, conecto no pc usando `http://localhost` e pelo celular http://192.168.xx.xx:8080. E gostaria de saber se tem como alterar o endereço do host para um endereço fixo(por exemplo http://test.com), para que posso acessar de qualquer dispositivo sem ter que pegar o ip do servidor(estou utilizando o Xampp).

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Eu configuraria o IP da minha máquina como fixo :)

Comment: então mas eu queria acessar por um endereço tipo test.com não pelo ip da maquina.

Comment: Que eu saiba, você pode fazer isso escrevendo um endereço no arquivos `hosts` do windows e apontando para o IP `127.0.0.1`. Agora, para que o celular também reconhece o mesmo endereço, não sei se tem como.

Comment: Não tem como, @WallaceMaxters. É um DNS feito apenas dentro do Windows. Caso ele queira fazer isso, terá que comprar o domínio e hospedar o DNS para sua máquina. Assim ele teria um endereço público.

Comment: Sim tem como. Se no ficheiros dos hosts meter o ip seguido do endereço, qualquer dispositivo NA MESMA REDE pode aceder usand `http://endereco/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Acesso via Rede Local (LAN)

Se estiver **na mesma rede** você pode usar o **nome do servidor**. Para saber o nome do computador no Windows [abra o Prompt Command](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) e digite `hostname`:

[image: Descobrindo o hostname]

No meu caso é `DEV004W`, então basta acessar usando esse *hostname* pela rede:

```
http://dev004w/
```

Uma observação é que sua aplicação não pode referenciar *resources* como `localhost`, exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/estilo.css">
```

Isso causará um erro, pois estará buscando o arquivo `estilo.css` na máquina que estiver acessando, então referencie pelo *IP* ou *hostname* do server.

#### Acesso via Internet (WAN)

Caso você **não esteja na mesma rede** do servidor (máquina rodando XAMPP/Wampp/IIS/Apache)  você pode utilizar o **[NO-IP](http://www.noip.com/pt-BR/free)**. É um serviço que provê um DNS Gratuito para IPs dinâmicos.

Comment: mas por exemplo se eu entrar pelo meu celular no http://dev004w/ ele consegue acessar o servidor?

Comment: Se eu entendi o que o Kadu quis dizer, "sim", se for na mesma rede

Comment: @Rafael como o Wallace disse e como minha resposta começa `Se estiver na mesma rede você pode usar o nome do servidor.`. Ou seja, se seu celular estiver na wifi do teu host.

Comment: @Rafael atualizei a resposta adicionando uma opção para quando não estiver na mesma rede.

Answer (score -2):

Existem diversas formas de se fazer isso, e a resposta anterior não é a melhor delas, mas talvez quebre um galho.

Existem duas opções práticas:

1. Se você quer apenas deixar algo mais bonito visualmente pra você, e mais prático, criar um virtual host pode ser uma boa. Um Vhost nada mais é que um servidor virtual. Você pode dar o nome que quiser para ele: [http://dev.test/](http://#) (se quiser). Mas existem diferentes formas para se fazer isso, em diferentes tipos de instalações. Basta "googlar" qualquer coisa como "como criar um virtual host" que você encontra fácil. **Mas atenção!** Virtual Host só serve no seu ambiente local. Nem adianta tentar acessar de fora da sua rede.
2. Se você precisa de algo visual para mostrar para seus clientes, tipo, "acessa aí pra ver como está ficando"... Você deverá criar um servidor e adiquirir um domínio [http://dev.test/](http://#). Isso vai ter custos (óbvio) e talvez dê mais trabalho pra você. É possível abrir o seu PC para o mundo tornando-o um servidor web, mas também é perigoso pois podem invadir seu PC e destruir seus trabalhos e seus sonhos. Aconselho a alugar um serviço de hospedagem web.

Comment: Recomendo trocar o termo nutella para outro que não caracterize ofensa.

Comment: Não vim ofender ninguém, pelo contrário, vim ajudar. Se alguém consegue se ofender com isso, é um problema da pessoa, não meu.